# PHP: preg_match `eats` my string

Tags: php, preg-match

Parsing code

```
$str = 'My name is Michael. I am a sportsman!';
preg_match('|My name is (.*?)\. I am a (.*?)|', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

returns me string:

```
Array ( [0] => My name is Michael. I am a [1] => Michael [2] => )
```

Where is `sportsman`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the expression is not anchored, or rather, the second `(.*?)` doesn't have a look-ahead set and therefore matches nothing); you should add the end-of-string anchor like this:

```
preg_match('|My name is (.*?)\. I am a (.*?)$|', $str, $m);
                                            ^
```

You could also make the second expression greedy:

```
preg_match('|My name is (.*?)\. I am a (.*)|', $str, $m);
                                          ^
```

Comment: Alternatively, it's because the second part is non-greedy, thus why the anchor is needed.  If you make it greedy (ie `(.*)|`), it will match without anchoring the expression.